# Get the previous element of a QStringList

Tags: c++, qt, iterator, string-comparison, qstring

I'm currently working on a small program where I will count the amount of times a certain word is mentioned in a text. But I only want to count for the word when the previous element is a 10 digit number.
So what I'm trying is do is that I will check if the previous element of the iterator consist of a 10 digit number. But I don't know how to iterate to the previous element from the iterator.

```
QString input = ui->listinput->toPlainText();

QStringList inputlist = input.split(QRegExp("[\s\n\r " "]+"));

unsigned int boxCount(0);

for(QStringList::iterator it(inputlist.begin()); it != inputlist.end(); ++it){

    if(!QString::compare(*it,box)) ++boxCount;

}
```

So I want the if statement to be something like this:

```
if(!QString::compare(*it,box) && *prev_it == 10 digits) ++boxCount;
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Might be simpler to just use index. Note that first string in the list does not have a previous, so you want to start your loop from 2nd item.

Comment: Btw if I see things the right way you are not changing the elements inside the list so as @hyde mentioned using index is a simple way and in addition to that using `at(...)` will be the right way to go since `at(...)` returns a `const` which can only be read (basically that's what you are doing here). Iterators allow both reading and writing. No need to expose something that is enough to be `readonly` to write access.

Comment: Also the advantage of iterating through a loop disappears in terms of boundary check if you manually tinker with it. I'm mentioning this because `at(...)` (which I have discovered only recently) doesn't check for out of bounds.

Comment: Ah, it seems that there is `constBegin()` and `constEnd()` for iterators in Qt to avoid changing the data the iterator points at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the previous iterator by doing:

```
if (it != inputlist.begin()) {
    prev_it = it - 1
}
```

You will have to make an exception for the first element, since it has no previous element. Either check the range (like above) or start your `for` loop one element past the first (note the '+ 1'):

```
for (QStringList::iterator it(inputlist.begin() + 1); it != inputlist.end(); ++it) {
    ...
}
```

In the latter case, you must be sure that your list contains at least one element.

If you then want to check if the number is 10-digit (assuming decimal and integer) you can try the following:

```
bool ok = false;
long num = prev_it->toLong(&ok);
if (ok && num >= 1000000000) {
    // do something
}
```

Note: I used the `long` type because I do not know the range of your numbers, but they seemed big.

Comment: Don't forget to check the range first.

Comment: You should check if `it-1` won't go one element lower. While the `for` loop makes sure you don't go out of bounds of the list changing the iterator inside needs the extra check. Otherwise we can do `it = it + 1000` followed by some action that takes the value of the iterator for a list of 10 items and hope for the application not to crash or create some sort of memory corruption issue that might actually remain invisible and cause a lot of headaches.

Comment: @SimonKraemer Added range check

Comment: @rbaleksandar The word I'm searching for will never occur in the first string that shouldn't be any problem. But I still don't get how I can check if `--it==10 digits`.

Comment: You need to dereference (by using the `*` operator) the decremented iterator.

Comment: @rbaleksandar I understand, but are there any function to check if the element is a 10 digits number? I found `isdigit()` function, but can't make it work.

Comment: Added a way to check if the number is 10 digits.

Comment: @PeterK Thank you so much! It works as expected now! :)

Comment: You can also go the other way around by converting `100...0` to `QString` using `QString::number(...)` and comparing the `length()` return value for both the dereferenced iterator and the number. This has the advantage that you need not cast your dereferenced iterator to a number (in the answer above using `QString::toLong(...)`) so you can assign the `QString::number(10...0)` to a const and just reuse it over and over again. Of course with my solution you need an extra `QString` in your memory.

Comment: This assumes that everything is a number, which, as I understood, is not the case. If not everything is a number, using QString::toLong will verify that it actually is a number.